# How can I list all of the possible entries into an array without duplicates? [javascript/jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json response that looks a bit like this

```
[{"name":"Dude",       "id":"1",     "Category": "One"},
 {"name":"Guy,         "id":"12",    "Category": "One"},
 {"name":"Thomas"      "id":"12",    "Category": "Two"},
 {"name":"Richard",    "id":"2",     "Category": "One"},
 {"name":"Harold",     "id":"3",     "Category": "One"},
 {"name":"Pete",       "id":"4",     "Category": "Two"}]
```

I'd like to be able to loop through this object, and make a neat array of all the different kinds of categories, for example,

```
["One", "Two"]
```

if I were to loop through this one. I've tried to create a for/if loop that would ignore a category if it's already been mentioned, but with little success. is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can review this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586274/select-into-json

Comment: I researched this question to the best of my abilities, searching google didn't yield this answer and considering it's title and contents I don't know how you came across it

Comment: Not to mention the question you've linked me to is for a different situation, hard to understand, and many times longer and less efficient than the answer T.J Crowder has posted below. If I hadn't asked this question I would have been left with that as a last resort (If I found it). and now I'm getting downvoted for it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with it. Just I gave you an idea for solution on the link.

Comment: Thanks anyway, your intentions were good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've deserialized that JSON response into the array containing objects you've shown (let's call it `yourArrayOfObjects`), it's simple to loop through and build the array:

```
var categories = [];
$.each(yourArrayOfObjects, function(index, entry) {
    if ($.inArray(entry.Category, categories) === -1) {
        categories.push(entry.Category);
    }
});
```

That uses [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through the array, and [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) to check whether we've already seen a category.

You could also do this without jQuery using [`Array#forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) (an ES5 addition, present on all modern browsers but missing, obviously, from some older ones) and [`Array#indexOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14) (missing from IE7 down), both of which are probably handled by any "ES5 shim" you might want to find and use.