# SAPUI5: How to filter data with 2 or more values

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently trying some stuff with/in SAPUI5 and I've implemented a very simple search like this:

```
    var filters = [];
    var query = evt.getParameter("query");
    if (query && query.length > 0) {
        var nameFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);

        filters.push(nameFilter);
    }

    var list = this.getView().byId("list");
    var binding = list.getBinding("items");
    binding.filter(filters);
```

Now I have following issue: with this logic I can just search, or rather filter, by the name of a person. I've also some additional fields like age, gender, etc and I want to perform a search for the age or gender, too.
So I've tried to create a 2nd filter, like "genderFilter", which is using the "gender" field. After this adding this 2nd filter with the .push() method to the filters[]..but this isn't working.

I've already tried to watch the documentation, watched different examples, tried different ways - but I'm helpless. Can please someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 8):

For the requirement this code will work.

```
var list = this.getView().byId("list");
var binding = list.getBinding("items");
if( !query ) {
    binding.filter( [] );
} 
else {
   binding.filter( [ new sap.ui.model.Filter([
      new sap.ui.model.Filter("name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query ),
      new sap.ui.model.Filter("gender", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query )
   ],false)
]
```

Comment: Have tried this , but it always return a `$batch requests must be POST` error, any idea?

Comment: will you explain the complete scenario how you are getting this error. Is it during a oData call or only during setting the filter.

Comment: Thank you ~ I've solved it ! it's because I used this in a datetime type data, how stupid ! I described it in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736210/how-to-filter-datetime-data-using-sap-ui-model-filter

Answer (score 4):

According to the API

> For manual filtering you should always pass the FilterType

If you change your code to

```
 list.getBinding("items").filter(filters, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
```

it should work.

See also https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/BindingAggregations.html at the very bottom.

Comment: Hi,

thank you Qualiture. But I've still problems.

This is working:

     var oFilter1 = new Filter("name", FilterOperator.Contains, query);

  var list = this.getView().byId("list");
  list.getBinding("items").filter([oFilter1], FilterType.Application);

But with a 2nd, it isn't working anymore:

  var filter1 = new Filter("name", FilterOperator.Contains, query);
  var filter2 = new Filter("surname", FilterOperator.Contains, query);

  var list = this.getView().byId("list");
  list.getBinding("items").filter([filter1, filter2], FilterType.Application);

What is wrong here?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Oh damn...I can not "ask" the question for 8 hours to have code blocks and the comment are very bad formatted..

Comment: Hi, can you try with 
`.bindAggregation("items", {
    path    : "/",
    filters : [oFilter1, oFilter2]
});`

Comment: Hi, I think  list.getBinding("items").filter([ oFilter1, oFilter2 ]);  is working now, BUT with this the query have to be in both values (name and surname). Is there a way to provide a OR relationship and no AND ? Thanks, Alex

Comment: Not sure if that's possible, and it's probably not even what a user expects; having multiple filters providing *more* results than having a single filter would provide...

Comment: Hm, do you not think it make sense to provide a search (or filtering) over multiple fields? Like a keyword search over multiple values of the data

Comment: Absolutely, but I think it's wise to understand a 'search' is something completely different than a 'filter'. Whereas with a search you're looking at (possibly) all columns, a filter basically puts a mask or restriction on your data to 'narrow down' results :)

Comment: Yes, okay thanks that make sense to me. Do you maybe have some documentation links for me, what the best way is to implement a search, like keyword search, for some json data?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679580/javascript-search-inside-a-json-object

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this with the below code:-

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("name",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,searchString);
var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("ID",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,searchString);
var comFil = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter,oFilter1]);
var oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("dealerList");
oList.getBinding("items").filter(comFil,sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
```

Answer (score 3):

to combine multiple filters you've to write the filter this way:

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    filters: [
    new sap.ui.model.Filter(col1, , ,val),
    new sap.ui.model.Filter(col2, , ,val)
    ],
    and: false
})
```

Source: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html#constructor

Then you can filter in multiple columns with OR.

Comment: This is correct! (Although it may seem wired to apply sap.ui.model.Filter on top of its own results.)

Answer (score 1):

Have only one filter in the `filters` array for each of the criteria and it should work,

```
var filters = [];
var sFilter;
var query = evt.getParameter("query");
if (query && query.length > 0) {

    if(query == "name" )
    {
       sFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
    }
    else if(query == "gender")
    {
       sFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("gender", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
    }
     //and so on...

    filters.push(sFilter);
}

var list = this.getView().byId("list");
var binding = list.getBinding("items");
binding.filter(filters);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer - but how can I detect, if the query is a name or a gender? Because like you wrote it, it shouldn't work - but I think the idea is not so bad. I just want to provide a search over multiple fields with one query.

Comment: what exactly is there in this 'query' variable and how are you getting it?

Comment: the "query" variable is the value of the searchfield - or rather the searchquery text

Comment: why dont you use a searchfield instead? use something similar to whats given here, https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/SearchField.html

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got everything right:
Here is how filtering more than one column when binding data to a table:

```
oTable.bindRows({
    path : "/modelData",
    filters:  [new sap.ui.model.Filter("severity", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, '2'),
               new sap.ui.model.Filter("severity", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, '3')]  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use both. So at the end this worked for me.

```
var oFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                filters: [
                    oFilter,
                    oFilter2
                ],
                and: false
            });
evt.getSource().getBinding("items").filter(oFilters, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var afilters = [];
var query = evt.getParameter("query");

afilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
afilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("age", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);

var list = this.getView().byId("list");
var binding = list.getBinding("items");

binding.filter(new sap.ui.model.Filter({filters: afilters, and: true|false}));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: How does this answer differ from other answers suggesting the same?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to bind two or more filters.

```
var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("value");
var oBinding = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items");
oBinding.filter([
    new sap.ui.model.Filter("column A", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), 
    new sap.ui.model.Filter("column B", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)
]);
```