# How to filter DateTime data using sap.ui.model.Filter?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I've tried to filter DateTime data using sap.ui.model.Filter:

`oTableSearchState = [new Filter([
    new Filter("Date", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),
    new Filter("Another_Date", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),
])]`

it return `400 Bad String`. I found that the odata request is `...$filter substringof(,Date)`. So I know it's not correct that using a "string filter" to filter date.

what I need is `...$filter= Date ge datetime'2016-08-17T16:00:00Z' and Date lt datetime'2016-08-18T16:00:00'` Can I do that with sap.ui.model.Filter? Or the only way to do that is put filter parameters together by my own hands?

Comment: I think you should create a custom Filter test function rather than use the generic filters. new Filter({ path: "...", test: <function> }) ( https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html#constructor )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, please use sap.ui.model.Fitler as (using operator [BT](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.html#.BT)):

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter("Date", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT, dateFrom, dateTo)
```

Selection of dates can be done by handling sap.m.DateRangeSelection event "change"

```
handleChange : function(oEvent){
        dateFrom = oEvent.getParameter("from");
        dateTo   = oEvent.getParameter("to");
}
```

Comment: Filter `Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"` seems not working, how to create a filter like `$filter=createdAt le datetimeoffset'2017-09-20T08:46:06.674Z'` ?  My result is `$filter=createdAt le Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:10 GMT+0800 (CST)`