# sap.m.list - hide a row

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem and hope to find help. On a sap.m.page i have placed a list (sap.m.list)

```
new sap.m.Page(
            "mainPage", {
                title : "",
                enableScrolling : true,
                content : [
                    oList = new sap.m.List("items", {
                        threshold : 2,
                        inset : false,
                        headerText : "Aufträge",
                        //filters : filters,
                        columns : [
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '45px',
                                //styleClass : "qty",
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : "Station"
                                })
                            }),
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '40px',
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : "Zeit"
                                })
                            }),
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '20px',
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : ""
                                })
                            }),      
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '20px',
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : ""
                                })
                            }),                                 
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '50px',
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : "Raum"
                                }),
                                minScreenWidth : "Phone"//XXSmall"
                                //demandPopin : true
                            }),
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '40px',
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : "Bett"
                                }),
                            }),
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '20px',
                                //styleClass : "qty",
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : "St."
                                })
                            }),
                             new sap.m.Column({
                                hAlign : "Left",
                                width : '20px',
                                //styleClass : "qty",
                                header : new sap.m.Label({
                                    text : "Typ"
                                })
                                (...)
```

For the entries i have a template definded

```
//Template für die Listzeilen
            var template = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                type : "Navigation",
                cells : [
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: "{Orgpf}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text : "{Uhrzeit}"
                    }),
                    new sap.ui.core.Icon({
                        src: "{IconTermin}"
                    }),  
                    new sap.ui.core.Icon({
                        src: "{IconAufbereitung}"
                    }),                                 
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: "{Bett}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: "{Bettnr}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text : "{Status02}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: "{Betttyp}"
                    })
```

(...)

The data for the list comes from an odata-service an our sap gateway. I fill the table with follwing routine

```
 var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Team", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, localStorage.getItem("Team"));    
            oList.bindAggregation("items", { path: "/AuftragSet", filters: filter, template});
```

This works fine.

Problem: not all entries should be displayed after loading the entries. After processing a visibile entry with a special type the corresponding entry should be now visible. I dont want to read the data again with the service, because i have not internet access at all places. Therefore i select more entries and need to hide some of them. How can i solve this? Where can i set the filter?

THX for your answers.

Kind regards,

Sven

Comment: On what basis do you want to hide a row ? Is it a field or a flag from your OData response ?

Comment: You can either set a sap.ui.model.Filter (you can find documentation on google) or play with the 'visible' attribute of your column list item

Comment: I have a flag in my oData reponse. A filter hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, Filter is not good option because you want to download all data and show select few. On the other hand, Filter will cause server to return select few rows beating your purpose.

You can use inherited `visible` property of `sap.m.ColumnListItem`. When defining your template add `visible` property and bind it to your OData property.

```
var template = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
type: "Navigation",
visible: "{put you OData determining property here}",
cells: [...]
});
```

Also, consider using `sap.m.Table` or one of its subclasses as `sap.m.List` with columns is deprecated. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.List.html#addColumn.

Use this link to decide which table to use: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/148892ff9aea4a18b912829791e38f3e.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: THX. Works fine.I try the use sap.m.Table in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering out the data that you want to bind the table is the good way to do. find the below link for how to filter the Table or List on success of your OData service: [sapui5-how-to-filter-data-with-2-or-more-values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29408282/3327698)