# How can I fix this find in JSON loop? (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, json

Borrowing from @McGarnagle [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679626/372567) to @ramesh [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10679580/372567)

What am I doing wrong that I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properly 'length' of undefined
```

The JSON part of   javascript:

```
var obj = [
{
    "list": [
    {
        "name": "my Name",
        "id": 12,
        "type": "car owner"
    },
    {
        "name": "my Name2",
        "id": 13,
        "type": "car owner2"
    },
    {
        "name": "my Name4",
        "id": 14,
        "type": "car owner3"
    },
    {
        "name": "my Name4",
        "id": 15,
        "type": "car owner5"
    }]
}];
```

The loop part:

```
var results = [];
var searchField = "name";
var searchVal = "my Name";

for (var i=0 ; i < obj.list.length ; i++)
{
    if (obj.list[i][searchField] === searchVal) {
        results.push(obj.list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `obj` is an array. It doesn't have a `list` property.

Comment: I think you want `obj[0].list.length` instead.