# Search inside an array of objects under an object property for a string assistance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using a JavaScript library that has some code that expects a simple flat array of items like this...

```
var items = [
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
    'item 3',
];
```

This is too limited for my project needs so I am editing the library to accept an array of object instead like this...

```
var items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
        image: 'img 1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
        image: 'img 2',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Item 3',
        image: 'img 3',
    },
];
```

The library calls some code like this...

```
if (_helpers.inArray(val, this.options.items) || (val === '')) {
    return val;
}
```

It check to see if a string is in the `items` array.

Because my `items` array is no longer a simple string value and is instead an object now.  This breaks this part of the library code.

The code for the function it calls is this...

```
var _helpers = {

    inArray: function(val, arr) {
        return ($.inArray(val, arr) !== -1);
    },

};
```

So I need some help in making my own `_helpers.inArray(val, this.options.items)` function which will check for a string value in an array of objects under the object property `name`

Any help appreciated

Comment: Try to use this:[Javascript search inside a JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10679626/4677505), it should help you

Comment: Where does 'options' come into this? `this.options.items`

Comment: @AdamJeffers I think `var items` is actually the contents of `this.options.items`.

Comment: `items.map(i => i.name).includes(val)` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be something like this?

```
var _helpers = {
    inArray: function(val, arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i].name === val)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z54qnukd/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping your array of objects back to the simple format:

```
var _helpers = {

    inArray: function(val, arr) {
        var mappedArr = $.map( items, function(item, index) {
            return item.name;
        });
        return ($.inArray(val, mappedArr) !== -1);
    },

};
```

https://jsbin.com/tihuyuquni/edit?html,output

Comment: jquery is really overkill for it. `Array.prototype.map` is there for years (and polifyll is available). PS: you could at least use consistent reference to a jquery object - either `jQuery` or `$` in both cases.

Comment: @zerkms good catch on the `jQuery` vs `$` - if the OP is already using the library, using it here doesn't seem out of step.

Comment: In the world where ES2015 is an established standard it's a step back for sure. Compare your code with `items.map(i => i.name).includes(val)`

Comment: It *is* awesome :-) The future is here for half a year already

Comment: Hm, looks like MDN has `includes` listed as 'experimental' and as part of ES2016: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes but your point is valid and I need to adjust my thinking a bit.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for checking that, I wasn't even aware it's not in ES2015 yet :-S