# Get the value from Json Array in java script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I Create the JSON Array like in the name of `jarray`.

It has id and the corresponding value.

And I have an another variable  `arr`.

Now, how do I get the value of the value from json array using id.

It means if i need to check the `jarray` by using the var `id=04`.

If i found 04 i need the value of the particular id like Apple as a out put.

How to use the If condition in Json array?

```
var jarray=[{"id":"04","value":"Apple"},{"id":"13","value":"orange"}];
var id=04;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON find in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946165/json-find-in-javascript)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
for (i=0;i<jarray.length;i++)
    {
        var tempValue = jarray[i];
        if (tempValue["id"] == id)
            alert( "value is : " + tempValue["value"] );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns an array of all the items whose id is "04" :

```
var matches = jarray.filter(function(a){return a.id==id;});
```

If you're sure there is only one, you can take `matches[0];`.

Note that this works with id provided as `"04"` or `04`.

To ensure compatibility with old browsers (which might not have the filter function) see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: in practice, he'd want to check `a.id === id`. @user, note though that your `id` variable is not a string, but a number, you'd need to change it to `var id = '04'`

Comment: yes, but it's not a best practice to rely on the "flexibility" of the `==` operator. it's better to use '===' and to ensure your values are of the same type

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0;
while(i<jarray.length) {
  if(jarray[i].id==id) {
    var val=jarray[i].value;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use something like [Underscore's _.find` method](http://underscorejs.org/#find), or write your own which might be more specific to your case:

```
function findId(id, arr, member) {
  for(i in arr) {
    // You could use === here depending on your needs
    if(arr[i]['id'] == id) {
      return member === undefined ? arr[i] : arr[i][member];
    }
  }
  return false;
}
findId('04', jarray, 'value'); // Apple
```