# Arrays nested in array JSON - how to access properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested

Struggling with some JSON I've been provided. It's in this format:

```
[
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "xxxxxxx",
                "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                "description": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "id": "xxxxxxx",
                "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                "description": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "parentId": "xxxxxxxx",
        "title": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "type": "xxxxxxx"
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "xxxxxxx",
                "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                "description": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "id": "xxxxxxx",
                "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                "description": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "parentId": "xxxxxxxx",
        "title": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "type": "xxxxxxx"
    }
]
]
```

So, I have an object named 'data'. If I stringify 'data' this is what I have above. Basically I have a parentId and I need to lookup that parentId in this JSON. I'm not used to this structure and I'm floundering trying to find a (relatively) simple solution. I'm used to having something like 'items' on the top level and I can drill down through that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11657379/1026459

Comment: JSON is a string. This is a javascript object (in this case, array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{if(data[i][0].parentId=='yourParent_id')
//stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed and you were first to post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a library, you can do this in [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org),

This:

```
_(data).findWhere({parentId: idToLookUp});
```

returns the object in an array where the `parentId` is equal to `idToLookUp`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrhrv/)