# Finding my object inside JSON by its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[
    {"ID":"5","Name":"Jay"},
    {"ID":"30","Name":"Sharon"},
    {"ID":"32","Name":"Paul"}
]
```

So I have this kind of JSON.

I need to easily supply the value for a required key.
For example:

- 30 would yield => "Sharon"
- 5 would yield => "Jay"

etc. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: If they're not sorted, there's no other way but to do a linear search.

Comment: Look at every object until you find the one you're looking for,.

Comment: Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946165/json-find-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Iterate the array and check if the ID matches

```
function getById(id) {
    var O = null;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if ( arr[i].ID == id ) return O = arr[i];
    }
    return O;
}

getById('30'); // returns {"ID":"30","Name":"Sharon"}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LLZ7/1/)

or in newer browsers:

```
function getById(arr, id) {
   return arr.filter(function(o) { return o.ID == id });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LLZ7/)

Comment: You could return from within the if statement to avoid checking the rest of the array

Comment: @bfavaretto - seems like  a good idea, and just returning the assigment should do that.

Answer (score 3):

Try a [linear search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search):

```
var searchId = "30";
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
{
    if(json[i].ID == searchId)
    {
        // Found it.
        //

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the IDs will be unique, and if you're going to need to do this frequently, then you may want to convert your collection to key/value pairs where the ID is the key.

```
var byId = data.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    res[obj.ID] = obj;
    return res
}, {});
```

---

Now you can simply use the ID to look up the object.

```
var target = byId["30"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just write something to loop through it.

```
var data = [ {"ID":"5","Name":"Jay"},{"ID":"30","Name":"Sharon"}, {"ID":"32","Name":"Paul"} ];
for(var i in data){
    if(data[i]["ID"] == 30){
      return data[i]["Name"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**undersocre.js**](http://underscorejs.org) can find a object in collection by one line code

**Reference:**  http://underscorejs.org/#find

**Code:**

```
var people = [
    {"ID":"5","Name":"Jay"},
    {"ID":"30","Name":"Sharon"},
    {"ID":"32","Name":"Paul"}
];

_.find(people, function(person) { return person.ID === '5'; });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YnfKU/)**