# jquery each iterating over complex JSON structure with "where clause"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I'm not 100% clear how to formulate a `$.each()` function.

The following JSON data block contains multiple items in the array `ItemValues`.  What I'm looking for is a method (because this packet can be arbitrarily large) is somewhat to get each `ItemValue` array item WHERE `Fields.Id` is equivalent to some value "x".

As well, is there some method to retrieve `ItemValues[n].Fields.units` as an array?

#### JSON:

```
{
   "CacheName":"Default",
       "LastUpdateTime":"\/Date(1396994130568)\/",
       "Type":"Start",
       "TotalItemsCount":3,
       "PassingFilterCount":3,
       "ItemValues":[
      {
         "Fields":{
            "id":"13288263",
            "status":"8",
            "x_cord":"7250600",
            "y_cord":"566620200",
            "code":"1021",
            "sub_code":"1W",
            "priority":"1",
            "units":"1011, 1130, 1201, 1233, 1445, 1501, 1518, 1714, 1726, 1823, 1825, 1832, 3662",
            "ts":"20140402234025UT"
         },
         "Id":"13288263",
         "LastAction":"add"
      },
      {
         "Fields":{
            "id":"13288264",
            "status":"8",
            "x_cord":"",
            "y_cord":"",
            "code":"",
            "sub_code":"",
            "priority":"-1",
            "units":"",
            "ts":""
         },
         "Id":"13288264",
         "LastAction":"add"
      },
      {
         "Fields":{
            "id":"13288265",
            "status":"8",
            "x_cord":"",
            "y_cord":"",
            "code":"",
            "sub_code":"",
            "priority":"-1",
            "units":"",
            "ts":""
         },
         "Id":"13288265",
         "LastAction":"add"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json to learn how to process nested data structures. Then you can switch to `$.each` if you want to.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks Felix, I'm aware of how to traverse data that way, I'm specifically looking for a $.each manner because I don't want to loop several times over the structure checking for a specific field equivalence.

Comment: `$.each` is just a substitute for `for` and `for...in` loops. It doesn't do anything that loops can't do. E.g. `$.each(d, function(k, v) {})` is the same as `for (var k = 0; k < d.length; k++) { var v = d[k]; }` or `for (var k in d) { var v = d[k]; }`. If you know how to do it without `$.each`, you know how to do it with `$.each`.

Comment: use linqjs it wins the game... https://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: @FelixKling I don't know what it was you said in that comment, but I re-read that and something just clicked in my brain and its all clearer now.  Sometimes, I'd like to kick myself.  Thanks and sorry if I seemed ungrateful in my first reply!

Comment: No worries, it's all fine :) Just wanted to make sure you know what `$.each` does ;) Happy coding!

Comment: You can use .filter on arrays

Comment: Did any solution worked for you?

Comment: Yes. I apologize, I forgot to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code which shows it all (using `$.each()` as you wish), using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var json_string = "Your JSON here";

//Use JSON.parse to make it an object
var json_object = JSON.parse(json_string.innerHTML);

//Will store the matched identifier
var matched_id;

//Will store the matched array
var matched_array;

//A valid test case, with units not null
var x = 13288263; 
$.each(json_object.ItemValues, function(key, item_value){
    if(item_value.Fields.id == x){
        matched_id = item_value.Fields.id;

        //Second part of the question
        var units = item_value.Fields.units;
        if(units != ""){
            //String.split() returns an array, by splitting the string with 
            //selected string
            matched_array = units.split(', ');
        }
    }
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CswAr/), to play with it.

*Note : there surely are some better solutions out there.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your json shown is in variable `json`, then for this exact scenario you could use:

```
function validItems(id,json){
 var validItemValues = [];
 var values = json.ItemValues;
 for(var value in values){
  if( !values.hasOwnProperty(value) )continue;
  var itemValue = values[value];
  if( itemValue.Fields.id == id ){
   validItemValues.push(itemValue);
  }
 }
 return validItemValues;
}
```

This same method using jQuery's `.each`:

```
function validItems(id,json){
 var validItemValues = [];
 $.each(json.ItemValues,function(){
  if(this.Fields.id == id)validItemValues.push(this);
 });
 return validItemValues;
}
```

For a recursive approach to finding json values, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11657379/1026459

Once you have the valid items, you can iterate through them, and then convert the units string to an array using split.

```
var validItemList = validItems(id,json);
for( var item in validItemList ){
 if( !validItemList .hasOwnProperty(item ) )continue;
 var currentItem = validItemList[item];
 var fieldsUnitArray = currentItem.Fields.units.split(" ");
 //work with array of units
}
```