# Finding JSON Array Object Values by KeyName

Tags: javascript, json

I am looking for a HashMap sort of implementation in Javascript for JSON for the following case.

I have the JSON with following structure:

```
{
"level1": {
    "level2": [{
        "product1": [
            "item1",
            "item2"
        ]
    }, {
        "product2": [
            "item1",
            "item2"
        ]
    }, {
        "product3": [
            "item5",
            "item6"
        ]
    }]
}
}
```

For my use case, I get a value , say 'product3', I want to find values for this key i.e "item5", "item6". I have a way, that i can loop through the entire level2 object but want to know if I can simply use key to find values.

Comment: Perhaps it starts out as JSON (e.g., if you load it via ajax or read it from a data file), but by the time you're dealing with it, you've parsed it and it's not JSON anymore. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: That's a very awkward structure. It's odd to have the objects in the `level2` array each have a *different* property name for their only property.

Comment: Why don't you use an object for level2 instead of an array?

Comment: check here, I think thats what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946165/json-find-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One-line" optimized solution using `Array.some`, `Array.indexOf` and `Object.keys` functions (no need to iterate through all "product" objects):

```
// json is your initial object
var key = 'product3', values;
json['level1']['level2'].some((v) => Object.keys(v).indexOf(key) !== -1 && (values = v[key]), values);

console.log(values);  // ["item5", "item6"]
```

**Explanation**:
`arr.some(callback[, thisArg])` - This function returns **true** if the callback function returns a *truthy* value for **any** array element; In my example `values` becomes `thisArg` parameter which should contain values of the desired "keyName".
It will iterate through all "product" objects, but will stop looping immediately if the required *keyName* is found amoung the properties of the current object ( `Object.keys(v).indexOf(key) !== -1` ).
As a concurrent condition it should save the values of found object which can be achieved with *truthy* assignment expression `&& (values = v[key])`.
That's all.

Comment: This is the answer, i was looking for. IT OWRKS !! Can you pls explain as well. Would be helpful.

Comment: @CodeMonkey, added some explanation

Answer (score 3):

You can build yourself either an object or (in ES2015) a `Map`:

Here's an ES5 example using an object:

```
var map = Object.create(null);
data.level1.level2.forEach(function(entry) {
    Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(key) {
        map[key] = entry;
    });
});
```

Live example:

```js
var data = {
  "level1": {
    "level2": [{
      "product1": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
      ]
    }, {
      "product2": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
      ]
    }, {
      "product3": [
        "item5",
        "item6"
      ]
    }]
  }
};
var map = Object.create(null);
data.level1.level2.forEach(function(entry) {
  Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(key) {
    map[key] = entry;
  });
});
var name = "product2";
console.log(map[name]);
```

We create the object (`map`) using `Object.create(null)` so that it doesn't have a prototype, and so doesn't have the pre-existing inherited properties like `toString` and `valueOf`.

The inner loop, on the result of `Object.keys`, is necessary because each object in the `level2` array has a *different* name for its only property. That's an unusual and a bit awkward structure.

In ES2015 (aka "ES6") with `Map`, it's very similar you just use `new Map` and `set`:

```
var map = new Map();
data.level1.level2.forEach(function(entry) {
    Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(key) {
        map.set(key, entry);
    });
});
```

Live example:

```js
var data = {
  "level1": {
    "level2": [{
      "product1": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
      ]
    }, {
      "product2": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
      ]
    }, {
      "product3": [
        "item5",
        "item6"
      ]
    }]
  }
};
var map = new Map();
data.level1.level2.forEach(function(entry) {
    Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(key) {
        map.set(key, entry);
    });
});
var name = "product2";
console.log(map.get(name));
```

Comment: So, is there no method JS library provides to do that ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: This *is* the way you do that in JS. If you're looking for a library recommendation, those are off-topic for SO.

Comment: I was looking for something similar to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: @CodeMonkey: That's what we're using in the first example: An object. I should say why I created it with `Object.create(null)` though.

Comment: Why is it a problem that your object-map has the usual object properties (i.e. `toString` and so on)?

Comment: @Roque: It isn't, really, in this case. But in the general case, when we use objects as maps where the keys are not known ahead of time, it's to avoid false positives.

Comment: I guess what you mean by "false positive" is problems such as `!!map["valueOf"]`?

Comment: @Roque: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could just transform data to different structure.

```js
const data = {
"level1": {
    "level2": [{
        "product1": [
            "item1",
            "item2"
        ]
    }, {
        "product2": [
            "item3",
            "item4"
        ]
    }, {
        "product3": [
            "item5",
            "item6"
        ]
    }]
}, 
  "level1b": {
    "level2": [{
        "product1": [
            "item1b",
            "item2"
        ]
    }, {
        "product2": [
            "item3",
            "item4"
        ]
    }, {
        "product3": [
            "item5",
            "item6"
        ]
    }]
  }
};

const transformed = Object
  .keys(data)
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    const value = data[key];
    
    return Object.assign(obj, {[key]:  transformLvl2(value)});
  }, {});

console.log(transformed.level1.level2.product2);
console.log(transformed.level1.level2.product1);
console.log(transformed.level1.level2.product3);
console.log(transformed.level1b.level2.product1);

function transformLvl2(level2) {
  return Object
    .keys(level2)
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
      const value = level2[key];
    
      return Object.assign(obj, {[key]:  transformLvl3(value)});
    }, {});
}

function transformLvl3(level3) {
  return level3
    .reduce((obj, value) => {
      return Object.assign(obj, value);
    }, {});
}
```

Comment: How does this solve OP's pb? I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Simple, now level2 is not an array, but object, so product1 can be fetch by path transformed.level1.level2.product1 and so on.

Comment: Oh. Never mind. I didn't see it was scrollable. I only saw the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

try (assuming that `level1` and `level2` is generic)

```js
var obj = {
  "level1": {
    "level2": [{
      "product1": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
      ]
    }, {
      "product2": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
      ]
    }, {
      "product3": [
        "item5",
        "item6"
      ]
    }]
  }
};
var keyName = "product3";
var items = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.keys( obj[key] ).forEach(function(key1){               
      obj[key][key1].forEach(function(obj1){
         Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(key2) {
            if (key2 == keyName) {
              items = items.concat(obj1[key2]);
            }
         });
      });
  });
});
console.log(items);
```